# Retrieving Data From Third Table (From Subquery)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, subquery, reporting

I currently have a query that retrieves users and servers (computer name) from two different tables. There will be multiple entries of the same user, which is fine, paired up with all the servers they have access to.

I am now trying to best add a third column (last logon) that is directly from the table audit_details (that I would like to alias as 'a'). I am not 100% sure how to match it (join) with the user field. Seeking some assistance! I feel like I've confused myself with how a subquery should be built.

```
  SELECT [user], [computer name], [last logon]='' -- LAST LOGON IS BLANK CURRENTLY
  FROM user_details u
    inner join server_details s
        on s. [Computer Name] = u.server
  where s.[SQL Server Edition] like 'dev%' -- Grabbing servers with 'developer'
  group by u.[user], s.[computer name]
```

Comment: why are you using group by in this select?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a select statement (in parentheses) as the third column in your select, like this:

```
SELECT [user], [computer name], 
(SELECT top 1 lastlogon FROM audit_details
   WHERE audit_details.userid = u.id ORDER BY audit_details.id DESC)

   FROM user_details u
       inner join server_details s
    on s. [Computer Name] = u.server
    where s.[SQL Server Edition] like 'dev%'
```